# Custom grouped table or buttons?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitableview

I'd like to design a view like this:

[image: iPhone_mainMenu]

Each "section", which looks like a two-cell section in the mockup, are actually or should behave as a whole, I mean, both the blank upper part and the lower part with the disclosure indicator should be an only tappable unit and navigate to another view, I drawed it like two cells because I need the disclosure indicator to be vertically aligned to the bottom.

Should I set two grouped table views with three sections each one? Is it possible to change the corner radius of a grouped table, the space between sections and the right/left margins of the table? And change the alignment of the disclosure indicator?

Or should it be better to design a view like this with buttons? Is it possible to put a custom disclosure indicator in a button, or such symbol is only intended to appear in table cells and may break the iOS Human Interface Guidelines?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have gotten your answer then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Collection views is the best for this.

Each little box with be its on UIView, reminds me of the card app they created in iTunesU, coding together.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

UICollection view is the best but if you need to support iOS5, in that case you can use plain UITableView create a custom UITableViewCell with the contentView you want with appropriate padding.

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this some time ago.. There are 2 options for you to develop this..

1. If you are supporting iOS 5.0 and below then you can make a grid view using TableView. (The code is in this tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/images-display-in-gridview-on-iphone/). Customize it a bit for your button and ImageView size.
2. If you are only supporting iOS 6.0 and above then you can use CollectionView and then customize it according to your needs.

Comment: You can always use a PSTCollectionView on iOS 5 and below.

Comment: @AriX .. Yes you can do that too.. but the grid i have provided can customized completely. You can do a lot of different things with it..